# laravel on virtual wamp host

Tags: php, wamp, laravel-5

I’ve set up a new Laravel 5.2 project with composer. Then I’ve moved all the Laravel folder into a new folder called local, except for the public folder. I’ve placed the files from public folder in document root. This to remove “public” from url. So I’ve found in some tutorial. Now I can call the site on my wamp server by typing http://mysite.

So far so good. However, the navigation I’ve set below does not work.

```
<a href="<?php echo URL::to('/info')?>">{{ trans('navcontent.info') }}</a>
```

Neither does

```
<a href="mysite/info">{{ trans('navcontent.info') }}</a>
```

Instead, localhost returns the error: “The requested URL /info was not found on this server”

What do I need to configure in Laravel in order for this to work?

Comment: have you tried https://laragon.org/ ?

Comment: No, I like to work with wamp. And how it will solve the Navigation issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with xamp. httpd-vhosts.conf settings:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAlias localhost
 <Directory  "D:/xampp/htdoc">
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
 </Directory>
```

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/mysite"
 ServerName mysite
 <Directory  "D:/xampp/htdocs/mysite">
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
 </Directory>
```

All Laravel content, except the public files, are stored in folder local. Files from public folder now in root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/extra" and open the file "httpd.vhosts.conf". It should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mysite
     ServerAlias mysite
     ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mystie/public"
     <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

after the directory code you just added,
it better

```
<a href="{{ url('/info') }}">{{ trans('navcontent.info') }}</a>
```

Comment: Your "httpd.vhosts.conf" can not work. There is no such directory in wamp root. It also not work, if I put my project root folder into wamp/www, wamp/vhosts and if I store it in the apache htdocs fodler.

Comment: As I wrote above: I've tried different folders. Start page is OK but navigation does not work. I set up the server with the tutorial on http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757 but only index page is working.